# Cutting off the lower end of a float

Tags: objective-c, ios, floating-point

This is more of a math question but I'm just not having any luck. Basically Ive got the code below to change cell colors depending on their row equivalent in the colors array. It all works very well but I would like it so that I could somehow cut off the bottom end of the brightness spectrum so that I never end up with anything say, below 0.2. Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)reloadTable {
    float arrayCount = [masterListArray count];
    float increment = (1.0 / arrayCount);
    NSMutableArray *tempColor = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (float brightness = 0.0; brightness < 1.0; brightness += increment) {
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:50.0f/255.0f
                                    saturation:1.0
                                    brightness:brightness
                                         alpha:1.0];
       [tempColor addObject:color];
       NSLog(@"brightness: %f", brightness);
    }

    colors = [[tempColor reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What is your error or problem?

Comment: Have you tried implementing a solution? What was the problem with your attempt?

Comment: First, it's not about your question but about your code, you should use integer loops instead of floating-point ones, rounding can mess up your logic (note that in this specific case it must be fine).

Comment: @HericDenis this loop is fine as he is checking brightness < 1.0, any how it can be checked. float loops are messy when you check for equality.

Comment: @Mike: If `arrayCount` is 10, for example, your loop on `brightness` does 10 steps, but, if arrayCount is 12, it does 13 steps, due to rounding in floating-point operations. You should modify the loop to use an integer for the loop counter and calculate `brightness` from the loop counter in each iteration.

Comment: so, you don't want low-brightness colors, why don't you just evaluate the brightness of each one, and if it's under the minimum you want then you multiply its RGB components to fit to the brightness?

Comment: Just start your brightness at 0.2f

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, I know that the loop will stop sometime, but as Eric pointed out, he can do it more than he wanted to.

Comment: Its not that I'm getting any errors, the code works well. I dont even mind that I end up with a few extra objects. All I want to do is not have black or very near to black at the bottom of my table, therefor eliminating the lower values out of my increments but still maintaining enough objects to correlate with my masterListArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some extra variables to make sure you always end up between 1.0 and the bottom end. In the below code we use the number of cells to iterate through (better practice than what you had before) and start with brightness 1.0 and end at your bottom end. Also no need to use tempColors.

```
-(IBAction)reloadTable {

    float arrayCount = [masterListArray count];
    float bottomEnd = 0.2;
    float brightnessRange = 1.0 - bottomEnd;
    float increment = (brightnessRange / arrayCount);

    colors = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
        // We start with light and go darker per cell.
        float brightness = bottomEnd + (brightnessRange - i * increment); 
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:50.0f/255.0f
                                    saturation:1.0
                                    brightness:brightness
                                         alpha:1.0];
        [colors addObject:color];
        NSLog(@"brightness: %f", brightness);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. I understand a few things better now.